# ERROR MESSAGE: Missing index.php—Child Theme

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to load a child theme on a Custom WP Theme that was created by another developer.

I created a stylesheet based on the Codex instructions but I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Here's my `style.css`:

```
/*!
Theme Name: Integrative Wisdom Child
Theme URI: http://underscores.me/
Author: Drew Lettner after Tony Klose
Author URI: http://underscores.me/
Description: Description
Version: 1.0.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: integrative-wisdom
*/
```

and here's my `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Comment: Put the code on Pastebin.com so that we can see it. Is the theme you are working off of already a child theme?

Comment: Thanks! Here is the code on pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/rhcu3fyc

The theme I'm working from is not a child theme . . .

Comment: Code edited in to question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing part of the boilerplate needed in the comments area at the top of the stylesheet file. You need a line that says:

```
Template: [name of parent theme folder]
```

For example if the folder in the /wp-content/themes folder for the parent theme is integrative-wisdom you would have:

```
/*!
Theme Name: Integrative Wisdom Child
Theme URI: http://underscores.me/
Author: Drew Lettner after Tony Klose
Author URI: http://underscores.me/
Template: integrative-wisdom
Description: Description
Version: 1.0.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: integrative-wisdom
*/
```

Comment: oh WOW! I am quite the n00b INDEED!  Man, thank you so much I owe you one!